# Can we use both of Form and xml validation in Struts 1.2?

Tags: validation, xml-validation, struts1

I have the folowing problem :

We have a Struts application. Basically it uses xml validation to validate fields.
I added Form validation to validate a set of checkboxes at once ( didn't find a way to validate that at least on of the checkboxes is selected but this is an other story ...) .

So my Form validation is working, but the xml validation is no longer working. But when i remove the Form validation i added, it works again.

To recap :

1- Only xml validation :  Working
2- Only form Validation : Working
3- Both XML and Form validation for the same action : Only form validation Working .

Can we use both of the validations on one action?

Tx

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the source of the problem myself!

It has a relationship with the order of Validation : 
In my case, Struts begin with XML validation and stores the results into a global object

**ActionErrors** : http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/api/org/apache/struts/action/ActionErrors.html

... After that, Struts execute the **validate()** method i added in the Form, but in the line i have the following line :

```
ActionErrors errors  = new ActionErrors() ;
```

... wich replaces the global ActionErrors object .

The correct codeof the validate() method in the Form must be :

```
ActionErrors errors = super.validate(mapping, request);
if (errors == null) {
errors = new ActionErrors();
}
```

.. this way we can keep the Errors already found by XML validation, and we do not replace them.